# Type 'State<List<User>?>' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to get a value from LiveData with observeAsState in jetpack compose, but I get a weird error

> Type 'State<List?>' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?,
> KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate

### Code

```
@Composable
fun UserScreen(userViewModel:UserViewModel){
    val items: List<User> by userViewModel.fetchUserList.observeAsState()
    UserList(userList = items)
}
```

[image]

### ViewModel

```
class UserViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private val dataSource = UserDataSource()
    val fetchUserList = liveData {
        emit(dataSource.dummyUserList)
    }
}
```

Comment: Bug report about this is here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192470278

Answer (score 312, accepted):

If you get a compiler error that observeAsState or getValue are not defined make sure you have the following imports:

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue

import androidx.compose.runtime.livedata.observeAsState
```

This information is from Step #4 in the "[Using State in Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state)" codelab.

Comment: added the getValue runtime import and also the listOf() inside observeAsState and it worked

Comment: Nice, It works. But why build `getvalue` and `setvalue` as extension functions of State rather than make them member functions so we don't need to import them separately ?

Comment: don't forget to add import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue too if you are setting values

Comment: I had to also add these dependencies in module level build.gradle file:
 `implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$compose_version"
  implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"`

Comment: Why isn't the IDE doing this for us? Is it really so ambiguous that deriving the necessary imports automatically is not possible? (Still happens as of Compose's release.)

Comment: I'm doing the first codelab in their basics learning path now and this is still an issue. I imagine this is v confusing for a noob.

Comment: This error doesn't go away for `mutableStateOf`

Comment: For `mutableStateOf` also add `import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue`

Comment: @vitiral December 31st, 2023 - The error still showing even if I have all the necessary imports, `...compose.runtime.*` doesn't work either

Answer (score 134):

To fix the error add the following imports:

```kotlin
// for a 'val' variable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue

// for a `var` variable also add
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue

// or just
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
```

To use a variable as a [property delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) you should provide [`getValue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#getvalue) [operator function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#property-delegation-operators) for read-only `val` variables and [`getValue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#getvalue) and [`setValue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#setvalue) functions for `var` variables.

To read more about how property delegates and state are combined in jetpack compose see [Use remember to create internal state in a composable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#use-rememeber-to-create-internal-state-in-composable) documentation section. There's also [an explanation](https://youtu.be/SMOhl9RK0BA?t=807) in [Thinking in Compose](https://youtu.be/SMOhl9RK0BA) video.

Comment: As of 2023 this (the last import with *) worked, not the accepted answert.

Answer (score 55):

For me manually/explicitly importing both the below apis worked to resolve this compilation issue,

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
```

Here is the reference,
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-in-composables

Answer (score 32):

You could use: `import androidx.compose.runtime.*`

---

Necessary imports are:

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf

var value by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
```

Comment: This was the one that worked for me...I needed the `setValue` and `getValue` methods.  Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I think type of items must be nullable since you observing LiveData:

```
val items: List<User>? by userViewModel.fetchUserList.observeAsState()
```

Comment: This is correct!  It needed to be nullable!  Thank you

Answer (score 14):

Just add this line manually below all the import libraries.

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
```

Answer (score 9):

I fixed this issue by just importing this:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
```

Answer (score 7):

Adding a dependency fixed the problem for me:

`implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$compose_version"`

Thanks to [Tayaab Mizhar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63875411/type-statelistuser-has-no-method-getvaluenothing-kproperty-and-t#comment117495201_63877349)

Answer (score 4):

You need to import

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
```

which will import this function which is basically `by`

```
inline operator fun <T> State<T>.getValue(thisObj: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = value
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following imports:

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue

import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
```

Src: [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, in a compose application it was this missing import that provoc the error

> import androidx.compose.getValue

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem despite imports! Took a bit but then I realised where my problem was the variable for whatever you're observing needs to be a **val** not a **var**:

In my case it was
`var background: Int by currentBackgroundColor.observeAsState(0)`

Should have been:
`val background: Int by currentBackgroundColor.observeAsState(0)`

Answer (score 1):

I add everything what You write here, but still dosent work for me.
I make 'clean' and 'rebuild' project - nothing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not working because you have used mutableSetOf instead of mutableStateOf