# var value by remember { mutableStateOf(default) } produce error, why?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm referring to the example in https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state.
When I code

```
var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

It errors stating

```
Type 'TypeVariable(T)' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate
```

The below works though

```
val expanded = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

// OR

val (expanded, setExpanded) = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

Answer (score 231, accepted):

Apparently, I have to include these imports

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
```

The auto imports don't automatically recommend it in the beta Android Studio 4.2

If you use livedata, then consider the below import

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.livedata.observeAsState
```

Comment: Similar one here, but slightly different. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63875411/type-statelistuser-has-no-method-getvaluenothing-kproperty-and-t

Answer (score 6):

It produces error because delegation functions of `MutableState` are extension functions because of that they need to be imported.

```
/**
 * Permits property delegation of `val`s using `by` for [State].
 *
 * @sample androidx.compose.runtime.samples.DelegatedReadOnlyStateSample
 */
@Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE")
inline operator fun <T> State<T>.getValue(thisObj: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = value

/**
 * Permits property delegation of `var`s using `by` for [MutableState].
 *
 * @sample androidx.compose.runtime.samples.DelegatedStateSample
 */
@Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE")
inline operator fun <T> MutableState<T>.setValue(thisObj: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
    this.value = value
}

/**
 * A mutable value holder where reads to the [value] property during the execution of a [Composable]
 * function, the current [RecomposeScope] will be subscribed to changes of that value. When the
 * [value] property is written to and changed, a recomposition of any subscribed [RecomposeScope]s
 * will be scheduled. If [value] is written to with the same value, no recompositions will be
 * scheduled.
 *
 * @see [State]
 * @see [mutableStateOf]
 */
@Stable
interface MutableState<T> : State<T> {
    override var value: T
    operator fun component1(): T
    operator fun component2(): (T) -> Unit
}
```

With

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
```

`getValue` and `setValue` functions are imported.

With Kotlin delegation you can either create delegation functions as part of the class

```
/**
 * Delegate [MyState] to this function
 */
fun myStateOf() = MyState()

class MyState internal constructor() {
    var value = 0

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): Int = value

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: Int) {
        this.value = value
    }
}
```

then use them without the need of importing since they are part of the class

```
var myState by myStateOf()
myState = 5
```

or define them as extension functions which is the case with `State` and `MutableState` interfaces.

```
/**
 * Delegate [MyState] to this function
 */
fun myStateOf() = MyState()

class MyState internal constructor() {
    var value = 0
    
}

@Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE")
inline operator fun MyState.getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): Int = value


@Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE")
inline operator fun MyState.setValue(thisObj: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: Int) {
    this.value = value
}
```

When you try to call

```
var myState by myStateOf()
myState = 5
```

you get error ask you to import getValue and setValue functions.

[image]