# Official documentation code gives `Type 'KProperty0<Int>' has no method 'getValue(MyClass, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate`

Tags: kotlin

Did copy/paste from official documentation:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#delegating-to-another-property

```
var topLevelInt: Int = 0
class ClassWithDelegate(val anotherClassInt: Int)

class MyClass(var memberInt: Int, val anotherClassInstance: ClassWithDelegate) {
    var delegatedToMember: Int by this::memberInt
    var delegatedToTopLevel: Int by ::topLevelInt

    val delegatedToAnotherClass: Int by anotherClassInstance::anotherClassInt
}
var MyClass.extDelegated: Int by ::topLevelInt
```

And there is an error:
[image]

I think I need some packages imported, like this answer does, but for `Intellij`, not `Jetpack Compose` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63877349/10777336

Comment: I've just tried in [Play Kotlin](https://pl.kotl.in/aesvUYBGY) and it worked. What's your Kotlin version?

Comment: Oh, It was 1.3, I changed it to 1.5 and it worked. Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code from the documentation only works for Kotlin version 1.4+. From [What's New 1.4](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew14.html#better-inference-for-delegated-properties):

> **Better inference for delegated properties**
>
> The type of a delegated property wasn’t taken into account while analyzing the delegate expression which follows the by keyword. For instance, the following code didn’t compile before, but now the compiler correctly infers the types of the old and new parameters as String?:
>
> ```
> import kotlin.properties.Delegates
>
> fun main() {
>     var prop: String? by Delegates.observable(null) { p, old, new ->
>         println("$old → $new")
>     }
>     prop = "abc"
>     prop = "xyz"
> }
> ```

So you should just update your Kotlin version to 1.4+.