# How to best relate my variable with state?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Say in my data class I have variable

```
var index = 0
```

In some Composable, the value of this index is observed and modified.  So from what I've learned, I need to set up a state in the composable like:

```
var indexState by remember { mutableStateOf(index) }
```

Then upon an action (say a button press), I need to update both indexState and index, like:

```
indexState++
index++
```

That's troublesome.  Is there a good way so that my original variable and the state related to it can be tied together and if one gets updated the other automatically gets updated?

---

Update: some clarification to my question:

Within the logic of my app, I already have a variable named "index" residing in a data class.  Some parts of the UI depends on index or reacts to the change of index.  In order for Compose to observe the change of index, I have to introduce a state variable named "indexState" that parallels with index.  indexState is solely introduced for the purpose of the UI and is not part of the business logic.  Since it has to be introduced, I hope it can at least be easily tied with index so that not much extraneous work is required to manage the extra variables.

Update 2: I learned that the introduction of indexState inside the composable is not needed.  I only need to declare index (outside of any composable, preferably as a class member) as:

```
val index = mutableStateOf(0)
```

Then in a composable I just use it like:

```
index.value++
```

So I don't need the "remember" stuff.

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of how you're using the data class

Answer (score 2):

```
var index by remember {mutableStateOf(0)}
var indexState by remember {mutableStateOf(0)}

LaunchedEffect(key1 = indexState){
  index = indexState
  //Automatic update index
}
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit){
  indexState++
  indexState++
  indexState++
}

  println("indexState: " + indexState)
  println("index: " + index)
```

```
I/System.out: indexState: 3
I/System.out: index: 3
```

i wonder why you want to bound two variables, we can find better solution.

Possible another solution;

```
var index = 0
var indexState by remember {mutableStateOf(0)}

indexState++ //->Update your variable before equalize 
indexState++ //->Update your variable before equalize 

index = indexState //->Then equalize 

println("indexState: " + indexState)
println("index: " + index)
```

Your viewmodel and composable class should:

```
class ViewModel (
) : ViewModel() {

    var indexState = mutableStateOf(0)
        private set

    fun updateIndex(){
        indexState.value = response.data-> Changes of index.
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun YourScreen(
    viewModel: ViewModel,
) {
    val index = viewModel.indexState
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it's quite a lot of extra code that I hope to avoid.

Comment: i think you have to different approach to solve your problem instead of bound-tied two variables and use them. Why you want to need that?

Comment: What's the simplest way?  I actually don't like to introduce the extra state variable.

Comment: updated answer maybe solve your problem, i wonder how you get the index in your composable, Do u use viewmodel?

Comment: Thanks, that's basically what I do.  Basically, the statement of index = indexState has to be together with indexState++ within a composable, as indexState only exists in a composable, so that's what I hope to avoid : having to update two variables.

Comment: i updated the answer, if you post your class, i can help better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where exactly you came across the method that you described, but what you need is state-hoisting.

Basic Principles can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state#8). This is how it works.

Let us say you have the variable stored in your viewModel,

`var index by mutableStateOf(0) // Use 'by' to avoid writing '.value' every time`

Now, you need to create a method in your viewModel to update this variable -- a method that can be called by any code that wishes to modify this variable.

```
var index by mutableStateOf(0)
fun updateIndex(newIndex: Int){
  index = newIndex
}
```

Now, in your Composable, create two parameters -- one to get the value and another to set it.

```
@Composable
fun ComposeIsPower(
 index: Int,
 onIndexUpdate: (Int) -> Unit // It accepts 'Int' and returns 'Unit', like 'void'
){
 //Use the Value Here as a normal value,
 doSomethingWith(index)
 //When you wish to update the value, just call
 onIndexUpdate(5) // This sets the index to 5 in the viewModel
}
```

At the calling site, pass the viewModel's parameters to connect the state-hoisting node, like so.

```
setContent{
  val viewmodel = ... //Initialize ViewModel Here
  ComposeIsPower(viewmodel.index, viewmodel::updateIndex)
}
```

That is pretty much it. You only need a single variable and modifying that will do all the heavy lifting for you -- no need to handle multiple variables like you mentioned above.

Consider taking [the codelabs](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics)

Comment: This shows the basic use of `MutableState<T>`, if you have a data-class, just replace the index in above code with the data-class object itself, it will work just fine.

Comment: Thst sounds nice.  But don't you have to set another state with remember inside any composable?

Comment: That's the point. You DON'T. You can't randomly use stuff and expect it to work, sir. You must go through the docs properly and chronologically to understand the basic principles of Compose. Take the codelabs. Have you even tried my code yet? If it does not work, then let me know (which would be most unlikely though).

Comment: Yes, I tried, in a simpler way.  It's great to know that "remember" is not needed.  It was confusing from all the materials I read which gave me an impression that in order for a composable to recompose, it has to remember and use some state inside that composable.  So it's not really the case.

Comment: You tired, "in a simpler way". Sir, if you do not understand the code, you cannot just make random modifications and conclude them to be simpler or something. PLEASE go through the docs and specifically the codelabs, OR THE VIDEOS, posted by the officials. You'll never understand compose if you keep shooting blind arrows on stackoverflow like this.

Comment: However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69855799/18612991) should REALLY help.

Comment: Thanks for the note.  I am not too keen at going through too much details.  The thing has to be reasonably intuitive.  Otherwise, my difficulties will surely be met by the bigger crowds