# How can I refresh my composable when new data is being inserted?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

My team and I have to make a license plate scanning app as a school project. With that, we have comments and pictures which can be added to cargo. Whenever the user scans a plate they also get the chance to change the checked info in case of a mistake. The problem is that whenever we delete data from the scanned plate it doesn't show on the screen that it has been deleted until we go to another screen. The same goes for the lazy column which we use for inserting new instances of comments and pictures. The data doesn't show on screen until we turn our screen or go back to another screen. private val pictureList = mutableListOf() is what we use for the pictures and for the text we use             var countryCode by remember { mutableStateOf(CountryCodeText) }
var licenseNumber by remember { mutableStateOf(LicenseNumberText) }. pictureList  is a global variable and the other ones are local variables which use global variables in the mutableStateOf. How can we make sure that the UI updates whenever the data changes? In advance I want to say thanks for the help! (Code is written in Kotlin and jetpack compose)

Comment: It is hard to understand what is your problem in this way. In any case try to use a `mutableStateListOf` instead of `mutableListOf()` for your lists.

Comment: Check this Google [Codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics#6). I think this can help you.

Comment: I've posted the answer since the loophole was obvious, but for future posts, I suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for learning what a question must be composed of.

Answer (score 5):

Just replace the `mutableListOf()` with a `mutableStateListOf(...)`, and prefer to keep all the state logic confined to a ViewModel. The viewmodel should preferably be only one for the entire app, and the entire app should have only one activity.

The viewmodel should act as a single source of truth for the entire activity's UI state, while also handling all the updates to the UI efficiently.

The `@Composable`s should only be incharge of **displaying** the state, and sending **events** to the viewmodel to update the state, for example, an `onClick` event may be sent up to the viewmodel by a button too trigger a state change in another part of the app.

Take [this](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state) codelab to learn all about state in Compose (Well, not all, really, but good starter).

Also, changing screens destroys all the `@Composables` of the current screen, and so when you ce back there, all the `@Composables` are re-created, and the correct data is fetched. If you wish to trigger "[recompositions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69855799/15880865)" upon changing a variable, you must ensure that the concerned variable is a state-holder, i.e., initialized with one of the pre-built state initializers, like `mutableStateOf()`, or `mutableStateMapOf`, etc.

We usually have a `mutableState*Of` format for determining whether a pre-built state initializer is available. The most common ones are covered, obviously, but if not, you'll need to create a new type of initializer yourself, and if that is not something you know how to do, currently, you can just go about checking whether the type of data you wish to store is [Immutable](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-immutability.html#0). If so, you can just wrap it in a `mutableStateOf<DataType>()` call, and it will trigger the recompositions. Know that this is not as efficient as pre-built initializers, but definitely gets the job done.

Also, I suggest you take the [compose-pathway](https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/compose) to get the basics down. It covers everything ranging from creating a simple UI using basic pre-built Layouts to creating a complex animation-driven application using custom `Layout`s.

So, definitely a lot to take it, but I hope you get there.

Happy composing,