# JetPack Compose, animateColorAsSate

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Getting error when use this line:

val surfaceColor: Color by animateColorAsState(
if (isExpanded) MaterialTheme.colors.primary else MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
)

It showing the following warning:

Property delegate must have a 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty*>)' method. None of the following functions are suitable.
State.getValue(Any?, KProperty<*>)   where T = Color for    inline operator fun  State.getValue(thisObj: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T defined in androidx.compose.runtime

Comment: Please add the code to your question, don't use image for that. Also describe what the warning message you are getting for that error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type 'State<List<User>?>' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<\*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63875411/type-statelistuser-has-no-method-getvaluenothing-kproperty-and-t)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you are using correct import statements.

Compare and try replacing your import statements with correct one from below.

```
import androidx.compose.animation.animateColorAsState
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color


@Composable
fun YourFunction() {

    var isExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val surfaceColor: Color by animateColorAsState(
        if (isExpanded) MaterialTheme.colors.primary else MaterialTheme.colors.surface
    )

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.clickable { isExpanded = !isExpanded }
    ) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rajasekhar, I have just replaced import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color with import androidx.compose.graphics.Color and it works.